# work_mem setting for huge queries

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am querying some data from a view using `copy (select * from tbl where id in (n) order by 1)` command (the table's in the view are ~600GB, almost all the columns included in the view) and it generates around 200Gb of temp files since my current `work_mem` is with default configuration. I know I must change few params to avoid temporary files. But I am confused on below points.

1. If the query's result size is > `work_mem`, will it generate more temp files / use disks?
2. Is it true that `work_mem` wont support more than 2Gb?
3. My RAM is 128Gb and SSD storage, how much `work_mem` should I need to use this for this query? (I will create a separate user to query this table, and alter the user's `work_mem`)
4. Is there any way to cancel the query before if it reaches out of space error?
   (I could limit by enabling max temp file limit. But I am not sure how the temp file size will be and how many files will be generated for a specific query)

(i.e., finding the more temp file/huge result(>10G) generating query, trigger `pg_cancel_backend` for that before it crashes the server)

Comment: You should also consider to tune [temp_buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY) parameter. Moreover I suggest you to set a limit for temp files for excessive usage with `temp_file_limit` parameter.

Comment: There is no reason for Postgres to push a `select * from tbl` into temp files, unless `tbl` is a view or something requiring building up results. Showing EXPLAIN of the select queries might give a clue about what's going on, as well as log output with `log_temp_files` set.

Comment: @DanielVérité, yeah. it was from view. I haven't checked it since its has similar name as a table. Sorry about that. I will update the question.

Comment: This is probably not the answer to your question, but it is sure a source for debate: https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/